# Correctly filter long JSON file

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON file with over 10k items and a lot of attributes and I would like to filter them by name.

I'm loading them by lazy loading and I'm printing them 20 by 20 as the user scrolls so it doesn't matter but now I have to filter them and I can't go through my 10k items to check if whether or not the name fits.

It would be too long and time consuming.

Another way to go would be to transform by a really basic PHP script my JSON file to my database (I have already the database working (with columns etc) so wouldn't it be preferable? I was given in JSON the things I was supposed to parse and add to my database)

What would be better to chose?

Comment: You can get 20, compare the names, if you need more to complete 20 you then continue gathering as many as you still need.

Comment: Wouldn't be too long if for example the first 5 elements are like 100-200 position and last ones are 9000?

Comment: For sure, but I don't see any other way that doesn't involve processing (almost) the entire file at once...

Comment: I'm going for an import to my database then, thanks you!